# Creating stub for sequeilze models with association

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I am using `mocha` and `chai` for writing test for RESTful APIs
I have read some articles where people suggests to create stubs for queries, and you shouldn't be actually making a database query.
*But How would I make sure if it works?*
See below controller.

```
const Op = require('sequelize').Op
//Models
const {
    Item,
    Location,
    Combo,
    Service,
    ComboItem,
    ItemLocation
} = require('../models')

const _ = require('lodash')
//Services
const paginate = require('../services/PaginationService')







const getAllItems = async function(req, res) {
    if(req.query.location_id){
        let items
        const item = await Location.findOne({
            where: {
                id: 1
            },
            include: {
                model: Item,
                through: {
                    model: ItemLocation,
                    attributes: []
                },
                as: 'itemsAtLocation',
                include: [
                    {
                        model: Service,
                        as: 'service',
                        attributes: ["id"]

                    }, 
                    {
                        model: Combo,
                        as: 'combo',
                        attributes: ["start_date", "expiry_date"]
                    }
                ]
            }
        })
        if(!item)
            return res.status(200).send({
                status: true,
                message: "No item found at location!",
                data: {}
            })

        items = item.itemsAtLocation
        let data = {}
        data.services = []
        data.combos   = []
        _.forEach(items, item => {
            let itemData = {
                id: item.id,
                name: item.name,
                price: item.price,
                discount_per: item.discount_per,
            }
            if(item.service) 
                data.services.push(itemData)
            if(item.combo) {
                itemData.start_date = item.combo.start_date
                itemData.expiry_date = item.combo.expiry_date
                data.combos.push(itemData)
            }     
        })
        return res.status(200).send({
            status: true,
            message: "Successfully fetch all items!",
            data: data
        })
    } else {
        const items = await Item.findAll({
            include: [
                {
                    model: Service,
                    as: 'service',
                    attributes: ["id"]

                }, 
                {
                    model: Combo,
                    as: 'combo',
                    attributes: ["start_date", "expiry_date"]
                }
            ],
            attributes: ["id", "name", "price", "discount_per", "description"],
            ...paginate(+req.query.page, +req.query.per_page)
        })
        let data = {}
        data.services = []
        data.combos   = []
        _.forEach(items, item => {
            let itemData = {
                id: item.id,
                name: item.name,
                price: item.price,
                discount_per: item.discount_per,
            }
            if(item.service) 
                data.services.push(itemData)
            if(item.combo) {
                itemData.start_date = item.combo.start_date
                itemData.expiry_date = item.combo.expiry_date
                data.combos.push(itemData)
            }     
        })
        return res.status(200).send({
            status: true,
            message: "Successfully fetch all items!",
            data: data
        })
    }

}

module.exports = {
    getAllItems
}
```

As you can see from above code. I need `queries` to return data in a specific form. If it won't be in that form things won't work.
*Can someone suggest how can I create stubs for such kind of functions so that structure also be preserved?*

Below is the test that I have wrote, But it uses actual db calls.

```
describe('GET /api/v1/items', function () {
    it('should fetch all items orgianized by their type', async () => {
        const result = await request(app)
            .get('/api/v1/items')
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
            .expect(200)
        expect(result)
            .to.be.a('Object')
        expect(result.body.status)
            .to.be.a('Boolean').true
        expect(result.body.data, "data should be an Object and every key should an Array")
            .to.satisfy(data => {
                expect(data).to.be.a('Object')
                .to.not.be.null
                if(!_.isEmpty(data)) {
                    expect(data).to.have.any.keys('services', 'combos')  
                    _.forOwn(data, (value, key) => {
                        expect(data[key]).to.be.a('Array')
                     })
                    return true
                }
                return true
            })   
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do that is by stubbing the methods from your models, i.e. `Location.findOne` and `Item.findAll`. So your tests could look a bit like the code below:

```
  const sinon = require('sinon');
  const Location = require('../models/location'); // Get your location model
  const Item = require('../models/item'); // Get your item model

  describe('myTest', () => {
    let findOneLocationStub;
    let findAllItemsStub;

    beforeEach(() => {
      findOneLocationStub = sinon.stub(Location, 'findOne');
      findAllItemsStub = sinon.stub(Item, 'findAll');
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      findOneLocationStub.verifyAndRestore();
      findAllItemsStub.verifyAndRestore();
    });

    it('returns 200 when location not found', () => {
      findOneLocationStub.resolves(null);

      expects...
    });
  });
```

I did not run the test, but something like that should work. But note that I had to split the models into their own file to do the stub. Probably there's a way to do the same using your current implementation.

Another thing I would suggest is having some kind of use case into your method that is responsible for database implementation. Something like:

```
   const getAllItemsUseCase = (params, queryService) => {
    if(params.locationId){
        let items
        const item = await queryService.findOneLocation({
   };
```

So when you call this method from your controller, you can do call:

```
const getAllItems = async function(req, res) {
  const params = {
    locationId: req.query.location_id,
    // and more parameters
  };

  const queryService = {
    findOneLocation: Location.findOne,
  };
  const results = await getAllItemsUseCase(params, queryService);
}
```

This way you will detach your business logic from the controller and you will have a much easier time to mock your query: you just change the methods provided to `queryService`.

You can find some interesting read from this blog post: https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html